# C# Semaphore state test thread saftey

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

```
public class ThreadDemo
{

    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0, 1);//Semaphore with maxCount of 1

    public ThreadDemo()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(WorkerThread);
        worker.Start();
    }

    public void NotifyNewData()
    {
        //New data added to queue

        //WorkerThread could be in one of two states
        //1) still working or 
        //2) waiting for new data

        if (sem.WaitOne(0) == false)//If worker thread is waiting for new data
            sem.Release();//tell worker thread to process new data
    }

    private void WorkerThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while(/*data in queue*/)
            {
                //process data in some queue
            }
            sem.WaitOne();//Worker thread processed all data, wait for more
        }
    }
}
```

See the above example.

I have a worker thread processing data from a queue and I want it to imediatly start processing new data when notified by another thread.  I don't want to poll for new data.

Will the above solution work?  Or, could this code potentialy result in the worker thread being blocked even when there is data that could be processed?  Maybe if both threads called sem.WaitOne() at the same time.

Comment: Your pattern should work just fine; another option to look at are reset events (manual or auto), depending on what your application is actually doing with the data. I tend to gravitate towards the manual reset event. Here's a good writeup: [Semaphore vs Reset Event](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4979abd-98e1-4d99-83ba-3ab8b5ad9fcc/difference-between-semaphore-manualresetevent-class?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Ditto to what @denvercoder9 mentioned.  Semaphores are generally used when you want to let a subset of threads (x of y) do certain things.  If you want one thread to do something when signalled by another, an event is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting events, I was not aware of that option.